# Motherboard with or without bluetooth capabilities

Tags: bluetooth

i am using Elementary OS. My motherboard is Gigabyte H110M-S2. How to tell if my motherboard has Bluetooth capabilities??

Answer (score 0):

If you have bluetooth, the bluetooth indicator should probably be shown?

Answer (score 0):

The bluetooth icon in the top right corner will be showing if you have bluetooth